# Using concat on redux state still modifies state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to modify some states to have them displayed differently but I can't seem to modify it without getting an error telling me to not mutate the state. I have tried using .concat, .slice, and the spread operator to copy the state array but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
const { cart, totalCartPrice, totalItemsInCart } = useSelector(
    (state) => state
  );

  const cartHandler = () => {
    const copyCart = cart.concat();
    copyCart[0].name = "New Name"
    setDisplayCart(copyCart)
  };
```

Doing it this way won't necessarily throw an error but it will mutate the state. If I dispatch an action with a button I set up, it will then throw an error about the state being mutated.

Answer (score 1):

- When you use `useSelector` this [returns the exact reference that you return, which normally means it's the exact same reference that's in the store state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397605/using-concat-on-redux-state-still-modifies-state/73398932#comment129642556_73398932)
- When you use `concat` this return a shallow copy of the concatenated array

If you totally want to change this object without mutating the state:

```js
    const copyCart = {...cart[0]};
    copyCart.name = "New Name"
```

- If you want to keep this in the state, this part should be in a reducer
- If you want to derivate this value from the state, this should be done in a selector

### Update state with redux

Moreover, this is better to do this inside a reducer as it seems you want to keep this change in the state.

If you are using redux-toolkit with immer, [this is the only place where it's safe to "mutate" the state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#redux-toolkit-and-immer)

```js
createReducer(0, {
  changeName: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
    state.cart[0].name = action.payload
  },
})
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
dispatch(changeName("New Name"));
```

Comment: Nitpick: `useSelector` doesn't return "a shallow copy" of anything. **It returns _the exact reference_ that you return**, which normally means it's **the exact same reference that's in the store state**.  No magic there - `store.getState()` is literally just `return state`, and `useSelector` comes down to `return selector(state)`.  No extra copies are made anywhere in that process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll update the post @markerikson